# Segmentation Fault when installing using pip (python 2.7.10)

Tags: python, pip

I am getting following error when using pip command in Windows 10 VIA cmd:

$ pip install numpy
Segmentation fault

> where python
> C:\Python27\python.exe

> where pip
> C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe

> python --version
> Python 2.7.10

> python -m pip --version
> pip 7.0.1 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

Please help.

I tried reisntalling the Python. But it did not work.
But now i cannot uninstall Python  giving error :
"There is a problem with this Windows Installer Pacakge..........."

Comment: Hey, could you try to make a virtualenv? "python -m venv venv" and then install the same, perhaps that will work. Not saying this is a solution per se, but might be a work around.

Comment: Any reason you still use Python 2? It's outdated for years, unsupported, and plain old obsolete.